# Is it possible to get the raw bits in memory of a double?

Tags: java

I was just trying to convert the following methods that I wrote in C/C++ to Java. In short, the code provides a very efficient way of calculating the indices of the left-most and right-most bits of a number that are set to one. The two methods are based off of code in Knuth's Art of Computer programming, volume 4.

```
// Returns index of the left-most bit of x that is one in the binary
// expansion of x. Assumes x > 0 since otherwise lambda(x) is undefined.
// Can be used to calculate floor(log(x, 2)), the number of binary digits
// of x, minus one. 
int lambda(unsigned long x) {
    double y = (double) x;
    // Excuse the monstrocity below. I need to have a long that has the raw
    // bits of x in data. Simply (long)y would yield x back since C would cast
    // the double to a long. So we need to cast it to a (void *) so that C
    // "forgets" what kind of data we are dealing with, and then cast it to
    // long.
    unsigned long xx = *((long *)((void*)&y));
    // The first 52 bits are the the significant. The rest are the sign and
    // exponent. Since the number is assumed to be positive, we don't have to
    // worry about the sign bit being 1 and can simply extract the exponent by
    // shifting right 52 bits. The exponent is in "excess-1023" format so we
    // must subtract 1023 after.
    return (int)(xx >> 52) - 1023;
}


// Returns the index of the right-most one bit in the binary expansion of x
int rho(unsigned long x) {
    return lambda(x & -x);
}
```

As you can see, I need to have a long that has the same bits of a double, but without a `void*` cast, I am not sure how to do this in Java. Any thoughts? Is it even possible?

Comment: Note that the “C/C++” code you are starting with does not work: it breaks strict aliasing rules, even with the intermediate conversion to `void*`. It only happens that most compilers generate code the correspond what the programmer intended. In C, `memcpy()` or a union are appropriate ways to access the representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a static function, [`doubleToLongBits()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits%28double%29), to perform the type conversion.

```
long xx = Double.doubleToLongBits(y);
return (int) (xx >>> 52) - 1023;
```

Note the `>>>` treats the long as an unsigned value when shifting right.

Reading the commentary, though, it sounds like what you want is a simple function of the [number of leading zeros.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#numberOfLeadingZeros%28long%29)

```
return 63 - Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(x);
```

I would guess this is more efficient on most current architectures, but you'd have to profile it to be sure. There's a similar "trailing zeros" method to compute your `rho()` function.